# How does Google Analytics prevent tampering?

Tags: web-development, authentication

I'm building a simplified web tracker as a side project.

One of the things I'm unsure about these cloud-based trackers (like Google Analytics) is how they prevent abuse of their platform; in other words, how they authenticate incoming requests.

I assume that they do some kind of check to verify that an incoming request containing a certain key (`UA-555555555-5`) is actually coming from the URL it is supposed to be coming from. Otherwise anyone could write a script to run the Javascript snippet N times to get N pageviews. On a conceptual level, not specifically targeting Google Analytics, how does a cloud-based web tracker usually do that?

Comment: It checks whether the `referer` request header matches the property for which the tracker is configured. That's the most basic check, although Google has lots of other magic for detecting and removing invalid data (specifically bot attacks).

Comment: There aren't particularly good solutions, and Google Analytics still gets massive amounts of referral spam. You could write a script to generate fake page views, and perhaps some shady people do that to mess up analytics data for competitors. You're not gaining anything from faking views on your own site though. In contrast, ad networks do apply anti-fraud techniques such as correlating timings, browser fingerprints, and cookie IDs to determine whether a click was legitimate.